# $\sigma$-compact open sets are precisely co-zero sets of elements of $C_0(X)_+$.

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove the following:

> *Statement.* If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space then every $\sigma$-compact open subset of $X$ are precisely the co-zero sets for elements in $C_0(X)_+$ (the non-negative functions in $C_0(X)$).

Let $Y$ is a $\sigma$-compact open subset of $X$ and $Y = \cup C_n$ for $C_n$ compact. Using the Urysohn theorem [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/tietze-urysohn-like-theorems-for-completely-regular-spaces/),  there are functions $f_n:X \to [0, 1]$ such that $f_n|C_n=1$ and $f_n|X\setminus Y=0$. Then with $f:=\sum 2^{-n}f_n$ we have $$Y = \{x\in X:f(x)>0\}$$

Here $f\in C(X)_+$.
But how to find a $f$ inside $C_0(X)_+$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose in your construction that in addition each $f_n$ has compact support (it is possible by virtue of Urysohn's lemma). Then
$$\sum_{n=0}^N2^{-n}f_n = 0$$
outside compact set $\bigcup_{n=0}^N\mathrm{supp}(f_n)$. Thus for $x$ outside that compact set we have
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}2^{-n}f_n\right)(x) \leq \sum_{n=N+1}^{+\infty}2^{-n} = 2^{-N}$$
and hence the function
$$f = \sum_{n=0}^N2^{-n}f_n$$
tends to zero for $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Ok thanks. The theorem is in Rudin’ Real and Complex Analysis Theorem 2.12. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes. It is quite possible that Rudin's book contains this result.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the one-point compactification $\alpha X$.

Then $Y$ remains $\sigma$-compact (so $F_\sigma$) open and we can use the same idea (using the standard Urysohn Lemma on the normal space $\alpha X$) to get an $f \in C(\alpha X)_+$ so that $O = \{x \in \alpha X\mid f(x)>0\}$.

Then $f':=f\restriction_X$ has the same property and $f' \in C_0(X)_+$ as required.

Comment: Very nice solution

Comment: @Slup thx. It's a standard idea on locally compact Hausdorff spaces, as compact spaces are much easier to work with.

Comment: Your taught me that Alexandroff compactifications enables one to deduce Urysohn's lemma for locally compact spaces from its version on normal spaces. I wasn't aware of that and I have never thought about it this way. Thanks.